# Need help creating a regex (NSClient++)

Tags: regex

I need to use a regex ("filter=regexp" in NSClient++) to get a specific line (which is marked with "<--") if there is **NO $-sign** inside of it.
Below is an example of what the text looks like in which I have to search (It is a description message form an eventlog).

```
A member was added to a security-enabled global group

Subject:
  Security ID: ...
  Account Name: ...
  Account Domain: ...
  Logon ID: ...

Member:
  Security ID: ...    <--
  Account Name: ...

Group:
  Security ID: ...
  Group Name: ...
  Group Domain: ...

Additional Information:
  ...
```

So if the line which starts with "Security ID" inside of "Member" **does NOT contain a $-sign** then I need the output of the regex to be "Security ID: ..." otherwise there should be no output.

I tried some different things, but I don't get I working totally right:

```
/(?<=Member:[\n]).*(Security ID:((?![$]).)*)(?=[\n].*Account Name:)/s
```

--> Wrong if there is a line between "Security ID ..." and "Account Name ..." and seams to give back two matches.

So maybe someone can help me with that. ;)

**UPDATE:**
How to do it if there can also be multiple lines between "Member" and "Security ID"?

**UPDATE2:**
Actually this is what I meant:

```
/(?m)^(?<=Member:[\n])(?:.|\n)*?(Security ID:[^$\n]*$)(?:.|\n)*?(?=Group:[\n])/
```

Thanks for your help Robin & AdamK otherwise I were still looking to get it right! :)

Greetings,
Cédric

Comment: If there is a line between Sec ID and Acc number, then i get nothing for match.

Comment: I only tried it here till now:
http://regex101.com/#python
and here:
http://regex101.com/#pcre

Comment: @Dobi: Fyi on regex101 you kind share your specific example by hitting Ctrl+S or clicking on "Save regex" on the left

Comment: @Robin: Ooh, thx for the information!
http://regex101.com/r/gJ0pV0

Comment: How are you using the regex? Is capturing the line in a capturing group okay?

Comment: Hope that works, bujt it should be OK, it's not well documented:
https://nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/CheckEventLog/check_eventlog
(regexp)

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is to distinguish one section (`Subject`, `Member`...) from another: we don't want to match *any* `Security ID`. This regex relies on the two spaces indentation to distinguish those.

The wanted line is captured in the first capturing group, see [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/oU3oD8).

```
(?m)Member:\n(?:  .*\n|\n)*?(^   *Security ID:[^$\n]*$)
```

- `(?m)` is just the inline way of turning on the multiline flag `m`
- `^[^$\n]*$` matches only lines not containing `$`
- `\S` matches anything but any sort of whitespace (no newline, tab...)
- `(?:  \S.*\n)*?` matches any number of lines indented by two spaces